# Ubuntu installation and updates

Tags: installation, updates

This is my firs OS change. Can I Install Ubuntu on a completely Formatted Hard drive? And do I need to install additional drivers from Microsoft or is every thing I need is on the Ubuntu DVD I have just downloaded? Also like Microsoft, does Ubuntu have automatic updates?

Comment: Most things are included and updates are automatic. If you need 3D drivers then you have to install specific drivers sometimes depending on your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can install Ubuntu on a formatted hard drive

2) you don't have to use Microsoft drivers, just some new graphic cards may need a driver which are supported by Nvidia and ATI

3) yes, and absolutely yes,Ubuntu updates are available and automatic :)